# Cant integrate admob in my flutter app,gettint error load code 3

Tags: flutter, admob

So i cant integrate my flutter app with admob .I use all the steps and still getting the same error .

Sript :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
  //   RequestConfiguration(
  //       testDeviceIds: <String>['my test id-i removed this for now']),
  // );
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CustomBannerAd(),
  ));
}

class CustomBannerAd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CustomBannerAd> createState() => _CustomBannerAdState();
}

class _CustomBannerAdState extends State<CustomBannerAd> {
  BannerAd? _bannerAd;

  final _adUnitId = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'XXX'
      : 'XXX';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadAd();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          if (_bannerAd != null)
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: _bannerAd!.size.width.toDouble(),
                  height: _bannerAd!.size.height.toDouble(),
                  child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd!),
                ),
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _loadAd() async {
    BannerAd(
      adUnitId: _adUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        // Called when an ad is successfully received.
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          setState(() {
            _bannerAd = ad as BannerAd;
          });
        },
        // Called when an ad request failed.
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          ad.dispose();
        },
        // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) {},
        // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {},
        // Called when an impression occurs on the ad.
        onAdImpression: (Ad ad) {},
      ),
    ).load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Also in my manifest i add this :

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="XXX"/>
```

What i do wrong , im always getting error 'I/Ads ( 1691): Ad failed to load : 3' even when i use test ids.

List of errors :

```
W/ConnectionStatusConfig( 1691): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE
W/ConnectionStatusConfig( 1691): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
I/Ads     ( 1691): Ad failed to load : 3
```

............................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads.

> i am writing here cause i dont have enough reputation to comment

Comment: Thanks for the response ,so i guess i wait some days ?

Comment: yup you need to wait for some days when i created admob acc for first time i had to wait 2 days for ads and now in my 2nd acc i need to waited for 6 days and if your app already  on any playstore then you need to verify your app with ads.txt to prevent ad serving limits, thanks for the reading :)